# Which Outer Planes are ruled over by a single god or entity in the Forgotten Realms?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities, planes

Asmodeus rules over the Nine Hells/Baator in their entirety - all of the other Archdevils answer to him. Which of the other Outer Planes, if any, are ruled/overseen by a single god or powerful entity?

Answers should ideally be sourced from 5e materials, but given the lack of detailed information about the planes in 5e at the moment, it would also be helpful to know answers from previous editions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Four of the outer planes have a singular ruling entity.

### The Nine Hells

As you state, Asmodeus is the overlord of The Nine Hells. (*Dungeon Master's Guide, 5th edition*)

### Mechanus

The only native inhabitants (as well as the ruling race) of Mechanus are the modron all of whom serve Primus. (*Planescape Campaign Setting*)

### Gehenna and Hades

Both of these planes are controlled by the Yugoloths (*The Planewalker's Handbook*), although their control in Hades is much more subtle. The leader of the Yugoloths is the legendary General of Gehenna, the most powerful ultraloth.

---

*Whether or not any of this has changed as a result of or since the Second Sundering (the event immediately preceding 5th edition) is currently unknown as 5e has not released much information about the outer planes yet*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76708/discussion-on-answer-by-david-coffron-which-outer-planes-are-ruled-over-by-a-sin).

Comment: I waited to accept this answer until Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes was released, as I hoped it would provide more insight into the state of the Outer Planes in the 5e timeframe. It has not - as such this answer is the most up-to-date information about this topic.